# folder structure for uploaded image/file?

Tags: upload, directory

is it recommended for creating each folder for each user to store the image uploaded? or should i just create an image folder and put everything inside?

Note: for web application such as ebay where each user will not have a  a lot of image uploaded, but they might be millions of users using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are other considerations to decide whether to create a folder for each user or
just a big image folder containing all images.
What is important? Ease of maintenance? Performance? Any Resources limitation ?
Will you ever need to persist those images?
What are the operations you will normally perform on the images?
How often?
Having a folder will be more organized, but you may need to maintain millions of folders and it will require more resources.
It will be difficult to maintain if the images are not followed any naming convention based on the user id or name if you put them in one single folder.

Before you decide which way to go, you need to look at the overall operations.